# Sqoop Job with password issue

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, bigdata

Sqoop job always prompts for a password in CLI. To avoid this it's been said that the property sqoop.metastore.client.record.password should be set as true. But everywhere it's said that I need to change this value in sqqop_site.xml. Is there anyway I can set this value to one job alone. I tried to create a job like below and sqoop fails to create it

```
sqoop job --create TEST -D sqoop.metastore.client.record.password=true -- import \
--connect jdbc:netezza://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/database \
--username username \
--password password \
--table tablename \
--split-by key \
--hcatalog-database hivedatabase \
--hcatalog-table hivetable \
--hcatalog-storage-stanza 'STORED as ORC TBLPROPERTIES('orc.compress'='NONE')' \
-m 100
```

Error :

```
Warning: /usr/iop/4.1.0.0/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/06/17 07:10:08 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6_IBM_20
16/06/17 07:10:08 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for job:
16/06/17 07:10:08 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -D
16/06/17 07:10:08 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: sqoop.metastore.client.record.password=true
```

Can anyone please help me with this.  I need to run a job witout prompting password in CLI.

Comment: configure these parameters in the sqoop-site.xml sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.username
sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.password

Comment: I don't want to change the sqoop_site.xml file. I just want to change only for one job

Answer (score 1):

You can save your password in a file and specify the path to this file with the parameter **--password-file**.

```
--password-file  'Set path for a file containing the authentication password'
```

Sqoop will then read the password from the file and pass it to the MapReduce cluster using secure means without exposing the password in the job configuration.

Comment: This is exactly how we solved this problem.  It's relatively secure as long as the location of the stored password is locked down through permissions and groups, etc.  In our case, we took an additional step which was to encrypt the password on the hadoop side, then call the sqoop command from within a wrapper program that was able decrypt the password before passing it to sqoop.

Comment: ./bin/sqoop export --bindir ./ --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBname --username DB_Username --passoword yourDBpassword --table tablename --export-dir /hdfspath